# python [oob] - data class with generator to get lazy evaluation

Tags: python, etl

I'd like to build a class which describe a data object coming from DB,
the table might be huge , so I was thinking using a generator and "release" row by row/chunks,
I want to add to the class several function which allow etl-like,
First, what's wrong with **iter** function - I fetch the first row only,

```py
class Data(object):
    DB_LOCATION = "./data.db"

    def __init__(self, db_location=None):
        """Initialize db class variables"""
        if db_location is not None:
            self.connection = sqlite3.connect(db_location)
        else:
            self.connection = sqlite3.connect(self.DB_LOCATION)
        self.cur = self.connection.cursor()
        self.loop_ok = True

    def __iter__(self):
      while self.loop_ok:
        row = self.cur.execute("select * from customers").fetchone()
        if row:
          yield row
        else:
          self.loop_ok = False 

   def transform1(self):
        pass
   def transform2(self):
        pass
   def load(self):
        pass

test = iter(Data())
print(next(text))
# getting first row
print(next(text))
# getting first row again
```

second,
How could i pipeline the data through the class transformation functions?
I think below approach might work for single row but not sure how implement it so it will process the entire rows in the table...
(pseudo code )

```
test = iter(Data())
etl_steps = [
        transform_1, 
        transform_2, 
        load
        ]

for step in etl_steps:
     test = step(test)
for i in test:
    print(i)
```

```
###Update 24/05
```

I change the code to gain lazy evaluation for fetching data from the table ,

```
class Data(object):
    DB_LOCATION = "./data.db"

    def __init__(self, db_location=None):
        """Initialize db class variables"""
        if db_location is not None:
            self.connection = sqlite3.connect(db_location)
        else:
            self.connection = sqlite3.connect(self.DB_LOCATION)
        self.cur = self.connection.cursor()
        self.cur.execute("select * from customers")
    def __iter__(self):
        for row in self.cur.fetchall(): 
                yield row           

def transform1(tuple) -> list:
      return list(tuple)

def transform2(my_list):
      return list(map(lambda x: x.upper() if isinstance(x,str) else x, my_list))
def load():
      pass

test = iter(Data())

#Working as expected
print(transform2(transform1(next(test))))
#now getting second row
print(transform2(transform1(next(test))))
```

The thing I'm not sure is how the transformation functions should implemented to get a real "streaming" nature (row by row) , When I use yield and not return - it didn't work for (even when i wrap each one with iterator) .
Second , this quite ugly solution to wrap each function with other .

I tried below but it didnt work:
Getting too many result and doesnt look the transomrations applied as expected .

```
etl_steps = [
        transform1, 
        transform2
        ]

for step in etl_steps:
     test = step(test)

print(all(test))
for a in test:
  print(a)
```

Comment: "First, what's wrong with iter function - I fetch the first row only," Hint: where in the code is the part that executes the query? Therefore, how many times will the query be executed? What does `.fetchone` do the first time after the query is executed? Will it be called again before the query is executed agian?

Comment: Please read [ask] and try to **ask a clear question** which is summarized in the question title. Also, please only ask *one* question per post.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel , I update my post with changes suggested but still have doubt for the approach , please see updated code in the post .

Comment: you should probably look up what the `all` function does and what it returns.

Comment: In order to stream one row at a time through the transformations your step functions must take in a generator and then yield transformed rows one at a time

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I got it straight now.  You want to use `__init__` to execute the query.  In my example here I just use a list instead of setting up the db file, etc.  Then you use `__iter__` to return self, and the `__next__` method to fetch one row and return it.

Regarding the second question, you just make each "step" function a generator that loops over the input and yields the transformed results.  Then you can nest them as you wish:

```
class Data(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass # set up db connection
        self.cur = [ # execute cursor
            {'id': 1, 'firstName': 'Bob', 'lastName': 'Jones'},
            {'id': 2, 'firstName': 'Mary', 'lastName': 'Jane'},
            {'id': 3, 'firstName': 'Joe', 'lastName': 'Smith'},
            {'id': 4, 'firstName': 'Jane', 'lastName': 'Doe'}
        ]

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        try:
            row = self.cur.pop(0) # fetch next row from cursor
            return row
        except IndexError:
            raise StopIteration

def transform1(data):
    for row in data:
        row['firstName'] = row['firstName'].upper()
        yield row

def transform2(data):
    for row in data:
        row['midddleInitial'] = 'X'
        yield row

def load(data):
    for row in data:
        print(row)
        yield row


etl_steps = [transform1, transform2, load]

data = iter(Data())

for step in etl_steps:
    data = step(data)

all(data)
```

Comment: This is not the correct solution. It's roughly how you'd implement `__next__` (except with a `return`, not a `yield`) to make `Data` an itera*tor* (you'd also need a no-op implementation of `__iter__` to go with it), not how you'd make a reusable itera*ble*; if you're implementing `__iter__` using a generator, you'd still execute the query in `__iter__`, but *outside* the loop.

Comment: @ShadowRanger thanks, my bad.  been a while

Comment: The class should almost certainly not be an iterator, rather, it should be iterable, and if it is going to be an iterator, `__iter__` should definitely not do anything except `return self` (i.e. not reset `self.cur`)

Comment: Ok I updated `__iter__` to just return self, but I'm not sure why it was bad form to put self.cur in `__iter__`

Comment: @Kurt because that implies if you do `iterator1 = iter(range(10))`, then `first = next(iterator)` and then did `iterator2 = iter(iterator1)`, you would expect either `second = iter(iterator1)` or `second = iter(iterator2)` to give you the second item in the iterator (i.e. `1`), and `first, second` would correspond to `(0, 1)`. But your implementation would *reset the iterator* (which is strange to begin with). The assumption is that `iter(iterator)` just returns the iterator object, without changing its state.

Comment: The class suggested will holds the whole data in the memory after instantiation , the implementation done in the __next__ just pop out a single row each time .... My question is for having a real generator which fetch a single row each next

Comment: @AviC I just used a list as an example.  using a real cursor will only fetch one row at a time from the db.  a cursor is just a pointer to the result set in the database